# Using draw2d outPutPort as a div child in a Extjs tree widget

Tags: extjs4

My goal is as follows:
I want to create two tree widgets in ExtJs and be able to drag and create connector lines between objects in the two tree widgets. The idea is to show associations visually between objects in the two tree widgets. I was thinking of creating the draw2d output Ports and place them as a div object within the tree widget DOM object.

Can output ports be based on a DIV object? I need to understand the possibilities of output ports better.

If I can achieve this, then I can place these output ports in any Div container and create connector lines.

Answer (score 0):

Ports can be added to any shape which inherits the class "Node". A node can be any kind of a div.

In general i think Draw2D or graphiti is not the right tool to connect tree nodes. You can use plain raphael for this limited use case.

Comment: thanks for the reply. This is just one of the use cases I am starting with. There are many other use cases. If I understand correctly, raphael uses a svg canvas object to create shapes, connectors/line etc. My objects are HTML DOM/Div objects...mixing svg with HTML appears cumbersome. I thought a more native HTML approach would work better for this particular use case. Your advice/guidance is much appreciated. thanks